# How to make an image appear when hovering over text in Flash cs3?

Tags: flash, image, cs3

How would the .fla that has text and when mouse is over that text an image appears  look like?

I was thinking to make the text a button and then add some script....

Comment: What have you tried so far? How has it not worked the way you wanted it to?

Comment: I have followed this tutorial, but I would like to do it in as3 http://www.flashperfection.com/tutorials/Displaying-Hover-Captions-Flash-MX--42089.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively simple

First, you'll need to make a MovieClip symbol containing your text.

Give that symbol instance a name (say `mClip1`)

Then, import your image and create a symbol from that too. Name it (e.g. `img1`)

Then, hide the image

```
img1.visible=false;
```

Next, add the MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT event listeners to `mClip1`

```
mClip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver);
mClip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mOut);
```

Finally, declare those event listeners and define them

```
function mOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img1.visible=true;
}

function mOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img1.visible=false;
}
```

Download the demo file (Flash CS5) from http://www.uploads.sc/download.php?file=749ce36c801a9bf18ce1b5033d8fd82f